# Deploying webapp with Web AppBuilder with custom widgets

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-web-appbuilder

I am new to ArcGIS Developer and I'd like to deploy a web app using ArcGIS Web AppBuilder with a custom widget. I have a personal use license for my ArcGIS Online organization, and I also have a developer account. This is where it gets confusing for me.

When I go to the ArcGIS Developer website, it automatically logs me in with my ArcGIS Online organization and not my developer account. With the automatic login, I can see my hosted feature layers in my dashboard. With my developer account login I cannot see my hosted feature layers. So it seems there are two separate identities. I get that but I don't understand why.

Can someone shed some light on this for me?

I just want to be able to use the Web AppBuilder with my layers and add a custom widget.

Answer (score 1):

The support article [here](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000021141) states that: ArcGIS Online does not support custom widgets.

However it suggests a workaround with the steps below (taken verbatim from the article):

> 1. Create custom widgets using Web AppBuilder for ArcGIS (Developer Edition. Follow the steps outlined in [Web AppBuilder for ArcGIS
>    (Developer Edition): Create a custom in-panel widget](https://developers.arcgis.com/web-appbuilder/sample-code/create-custom-in-panel-widget.htm).
> 2. Host the application with the custom widgets on the organization's web server. Refer to [Web AppBuilder for ArcGIS: Deploy the app](https://developers.arcgis.com/web-appbuilder/guide/xt-deploy-app.htm#GUID-DE10C2E7-51B9-46C7-864E-E0B69DA49203) for
>    steps to do this.
> 3. Add the application as an item in ArcGIS Online. Refer to [ArcGIS Online: Add apps](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/manage-data/add-items.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_0D1B620254F745AE84F394289F8AF44B) for steps to do this.

The language is confusing as it suggests that the application created with Web AppBuilder Developer's Edition (or WAB-DE) and using custom widgets, can be deployed on ArcGIS online - this is NOT the case, a separate web server is needed. Your ArcGIS online developer account (assuming with proper roles granted) will give you [access to WAB and WAB-DE tools](https://developers.arcgis.com/web-appbuilder/guide/getstarted.htm), but you will not be able to do anything involving custom widgets on ArcGIS online itself (apart from the steps described above).